# Falla en excepción y la respuesta de error

Tags: laravel

Tengo el siguiente controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
       
         
public function store(Request $request){

    $request->validate([
        'precio' => 'required',
    ]);
}
```

El problema que tengo es que si hago clic en el boton enviar y tengo el input vacio (null).

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" value="" name="precio[]" id="precio">
```

Busca guardar en la base de datos y luego me viene el error de la base de datos que el campo no se puede guardar null.

Alguien me podría indicar que cambio en laravel 8?
Porque siempre lo puse así y validó sin temas.

Es más, para probar metí lo siguiente:  `'precio' => 'hola',` y me salto error quiere decir que entra pero ignora la validación 'required'.

Comment: ¿retornar el error, o detienes la ejecución cuando detecta el error en la validación?

Comment: no detecta error en  $request->validate, busca guardar el registro como si estuviera bien ingresado el formulario con el precio null, me salta el error en la base de datos porque alli lo tengo restringido

Comment: si lo detecta, pero me imagino que no detienes la ejecución, te mando la liga de la documentación que explica el funcionamiento del valídate: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic

Comment: a que te refieres con que no detengo la ejecución? siempre use las validaciones y si consigue un dato required muestra el error en pantalla para que el usuario sepa que le falta completar el error, en mi caso no lo muestra

Comment: en la documentacion dice: "Si pasan las reglas de validación, su código seguirá ejecutándose normalmente; sin embargo, si la validación falla, se lanzará una excepción y la respuesta de error adecuada se enviará automáticamente al usuario" en mi caso no me lanza la excepción.

Comment: ¿No será que está enviando cero o un string vacío en vez de null y después hace la comparación estricta?

Comment: Deberías mostrar cómo estás enviando el request para ese método.

Comment: se estan enviaando como null porque lo imprimí para ver que estaba llegando, de todas editaré mi pregunta para que se vea como estoy enviando el campo

Comment: gracias por la ayuda busco información para validar array

Comment: eres el mejor me sirvió de 10

Comment: lo que no se es como coloco tu respuesta como la aceptada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como su nombre lo indica `name="precio[]"`, el input precio [se envía como un array](https://www.php.net/manual/es/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays):

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" value="" name="precio[]" id="precio">
```

Tendrías que validar que tenga al menos un elemento, porque si pones sólo la regla `required`, un array vacío también pasaría la validación.

Te puede servir algo como:

```
$request->validate([
    'precio' => 'required|array|min:1', 
    'precio.*' => 'required|numeric',
]);
```

Pero hay varias formas de hacerlo. Puedes leer más en:

[Validating Arrays](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-arrays).
[Rule Array](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-array)